# how to run second program

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, ecmascript-6

1. ---

   -- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

   var operators = { '+': function(a, b) {  return a + b  },  '-':
   function(a, b) {  return a - b  },  '*': function(a, b) {  return a

   - b  },  '/': function(a, b) {
         return a / b
       }
     };

   var op = '/'; console.log(operators[op](10, 10)); //it works correct

   var operators = [{ '+': function(a, b) { return a + b }, '-':
   function(a, b) { return a - b  },  '*': function(a, b) { return a *
   b  }, '/': function(a, b) { return a / b } }]; var op = '/';

   l please help me......how run second program

Comment: What  is a function in array?

Comment: What is this obfuscated code? please format it to a readable form.

Comment: What second program? Your "question" is completely unclear.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `console.log(operators[0][op](10, 10))` would be your answer but all that makes no real sense... You need to provide more details

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you should use `find()`:

```
console.log(operators.find(e => Object.keys(e).includes(op))[op](10, 10));
```

ES5:

```
console.log(operators.find(function(e) {
    return Object.keys(e).indexOf(op) > -1;
})[op](10, 10));
```

Comment: includes is not in the ECMAScript 5 specification

Answer (score 0):

You can use Switch case as well

```
function calculate(a,b,op) {
 switch (op) {
  case '+':
    return a + b;
    break;
  case '-':
    return a - b;
    break;
  case '*':
    return a * b;
    break;
  case '/':
    return a / b;
    break;
 default: 
    return "No operator found";
}
}
var op = '+'
calculate(5,5,'op')
```